# nginx SSI include, coming up as corrupts code?

Tags: nginx, server-side-includes

I'm trying to get some `SSI` calls setup on a *.html* page with **nginx**. The following works fine:

```
        <center><!--# include file="total.txt" -->
            <br /><br /><a href="donate.html">Do your part - donate!</a>
        </center>
```

[image]

...but this one comes up as garbage (it should show a calendar, and works fine when I call the script manually in the browser);

```
<center><!--# include virtual="cal.cgi" --></center>
```

[image]

I have SSI enabled in the `location /` block:

```
location / {

    ssi on;

    # all the other stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That garbage looks like Latin rendered as UTF-8. Make sure that you are using a consistent CHARSET throughout.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for the reply. I'm not sure its that. The content is only basic stuff like: `<table class="calendar"><tr><td colspan="3" align="left"><b><small>[<a href="` etc... so not exactly a lot to get wrong with encoding :)

Comment: Mmm ok, so this seems to be an issue with me doing a proxy_pass to Apache, from nginx. The only way I've managed to get it to work is by using a `$.get()` ajax request to grab the contents, and then place it on the page. Not ideal, but I've already wasted too long on this :(